# What is the best to render multiple google map markers in DJANGO template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-maps, django-templates

I have looked into similar questions but they have different implementations method therefore i am kind of stuck trying to render a queryset from the view template to be displayed on Google map.

## models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=8)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=8)
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    locations = Location.objects.all()

    context = {'locations':locations}
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context)
```

## html

## locations currently hardcoded

```
{% for activity in activities %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [
          ['Stadtbibliothek Zanklhof', 47.06976, 15.43154, 1],
          ['Stadtbibliothek dieMediathek', 47.06975, 15.43116, 2],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Gösting', 47.09399, 15.40548, 3],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Graz West', 47.06993, 15.40727, 4],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Graz Ost', 47.06934, 15.45888, 5],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Graz Süd', 47.04572, 15.43234, 6],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Graz Nord', 47.08350, 15.43212, 7],
          ['Stadtbibliothek Andritz', 47.10280, 15.42137, 8]
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.071876, 15.441456),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
    </script>
    {% endfor %}
```

I am just stuck on how and where to place the tags   `{{ activity.longitude }}` and `{{ activity.latitude }}`. Tried multiple approaches to solve the problem but it end up not rendering google map.

If anyone could help I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be better to do the processing at the server side. So we can construct a view that will create a JSON blob:

```
import json

def index(request):
    locations = [
        [l.name, l.latitude, l.longitude, i]
        for i, l in enumerate(Location.objects.all())
    ]
    context = {'locations': json.dumps(locations)}
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context)
```

In the template we then just pass this to the location variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = {{ locations|safe }};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.071876, 15.441456),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @CurtisBanks: no since that is the javascript talking. Can you show what `var locations = ...` is rendering?

Comment: The page only render the map without any marker with the latitude + logitude of ```center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.071876, 15.441456),``` on the code above

Comment: @CurtisBanks: but what does it say on the line `var locations = ` in the *rendered* template?

Comment: good catch. from ```inspect=>source ``` tell me that ```var locations = [["Soccer @ Union Square Park", "40.736481", "-73.988243", 0], ["Dream team @ East village", "40.727852", "-73.982224", 1]];``` the value are there. i believe it is just not properly rendered. any suggestions?